# how to Assign roles to User while creating their account

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am using asp.net built-in membership and role provider.

In my application Admin Create account for user.

currently i am assigning roles by going to asp.net configuration website.

kindly tell me how to add an extra step of Select Role in creat user account API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you just asking how to assign a User to a Role?

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, roleName);
```

And to remove a role:

```
Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(userName, roleName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to : http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/assigning-roles-to-users-cs