# assign role to user at account creation asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, user-accounts, role

I'm still a student and I'm learning C#. I have to make a little application in ASP.NET. The application has to use roles.

So, I "linked" a MemberShip to my database (with the tool asp_regsql). Now I have all the asp tables so it's ok. I created 2 roles (Admin & Client) with the ASP configuration tools.

My question is :

Is it possible to create a page (like Register.aspx) and in this page to pass a hide parameter to set the user role at the registration ?

For example, I would have a page RegisterClient.aspx and when an user create an account on this page, the account is automaticaly associated to the Client role.

Is-it possible or have I to do this by myself with the ASP configurator ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You have to do it your self on the code behind page, right after the user is register, you associate him the role. Its not that difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to Assign roles to User while creating their account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333740/how-to-assign-roles-to-user-while-creating-their-account)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add this Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "roleName"); to the onregistered event handler of the register control.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it by yourself in code behind something like this to assign a role to the user:-

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUser1" runat="server" Width="435" OnCreatedUser="CreatedUser" CreateUserButtonType="Link">

public void CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUser1.UserName, "Members");
}
```