# How to give user access in MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to give the user access according to the user role.
I have two user roles. they are Admin and user.

I write my controller like this.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] // my Problem is here. I don't know how to set the current user role

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var query = from company in db.tblCompanies
                select company;
    return View(query.ToList());
}
```

But I don't know how to set the `Roles = "Admin"` after cutomer login.
In my user tale I have Roles  coloum and it can save Admin or user.
But I don't know how to set and where should I set `Roles = "Admin".`

Comment: This question is very hard to understand. Can you make it more clear?

Comment: So are you leveraging the default users and roles providers or do you have a custom user table?

Comment: I have custom user table. I don't know how to set the current user role. I can get it from data base. But I don't know hoe to set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question what I get is  you want to set the currently logged user to some role. So here is my answer to that.

**To Add a User to a Role:**

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, roleName);
```

**To Remove a User from a Role:**

```
Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(userName, roleName);
```

Reference Links:

1. [SO - How to Assign roles to User while creating their account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333796/468718)
2. [MSDN - Implementing a Custom Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx)
3. [MSDN - Roles.AddUserToRole Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx)
4. [MSDN - Roles.RemoveUserFromRole Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.removeuserfromrole.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this :

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7

You basically assign roles to your users via the ASP.NET Configuration website. Once done the user - role mapping is handled by default.